# highcharts datalabel text reversed

Tags: html, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to generate a stacked column chart , but if the numbers are greater than thousand it is reversed in the highchart datalabel. as you can see in the image any help?.[image: the numbers supposed to be 1104,1211]

Comment: Can you provide the code thats being used to generate the chart.

Comment: and can you verify how it is supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to add comma for thousand number . and it's done with highcharts by this code : 
Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang: {
                        thousandsSep: ','
                    }
                });